# User registration is currently not allowed

Tags: multisite, buddypress, user-registration, multisite-user-management

I'm running into issues on my localhost where when I navigate to my registration page I get the following error message *User registration is currently not allowed.*

What I've tried so far:

1. I've checked my settings menu under `wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=1` and under *Users can register* I have a `1` entered.
2. I've tried turning my plugins on and off.
3. I've checked `wp-admin/admin.php?page=bp-page-settings` and all necessary pages exist and are listed.
4. I've tried echoing `wp_register('','',false);` to see if that lends any clues and it just turns up blank.

This isn't the case on my other server (which I had thought was configured identically to my localhost).  Registration is allowed and the echo above provides the link.  No idea what's going on here and am working against a deadline (aren't we all, right?) so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable registration on the network? wp-admin/network/settings.php

Comment: hah, just did as you posted that. :-P  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sooner did I post than I ran across [this forum thread](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/user-registration-is-currently-not-allowed/).  I had to go into `Network Admin > Settings > Network Settings`  There, I had to select "User Accounts may be registered"  in addition to entering a 1 in the site settings area.  Problem solved.  Maybe this helps someone else.